# I did something and now my viewport is view is odd

Tags: 3d-view, interface, wireframe

I did something now viewport solid looks like this:

[image]

There is a point somewhere out at infinity projected through the shape and the only 2 faces showing are the ones in the projection. Material preview mode looks normal.

What did I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled a **Clipping Region** (Shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> - easy to do by mistake). You can clear it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> again.

[image: Region]

Comment: That was it, thanks! I've been learning to use the 'bevel' setting, Alt+B instead of Ctrl+B

Comment: Yeah, like I said - easy mistake. If you can see from my image though, `Ctrl + B` in _Object Mode_ will define a render region - make sure you're in _Edit Mode_ if you plan to Bevel.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description, but it's possible that you hid the polygons of your mesh (or your objects) by pressing *H*. You can un-hide them with *Alt+H*. This feature exists because as models get more complicated and edits need to be more precise, sometimes hiding an area outright benefits the user. This only effects the workspace, it does not show up in the render.

Unfortunately the *H* key is very close to the *G* key on a QWERTY keyboard!

In the event that I'm misinterpreting you and you simply have your camera at a funny angle, you can get back to the default by going into object mode and pressing *Shift+C*.